# How to call controller function from view by external javascript in Laravel 7?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

My Email verification worked flawlessly until I tried putting the javascript from the view `emailvali.blade.php` to an external javascript file. The following code was moved from the view file to /public/js/emailvali.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       

 $('#email').blur(function(){

  var error_email = '';
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

  if(!filter.test(email))
  {    
   $('#error_email').html('<label class="text-danger">Invalid Email format</label>');
   $('#email').addClass('has-error');
   $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  else
  {
  $('#error_email').html('<label class="text-success">Email format valid</label>');
  let email = document.getElementById("email").value; //assuming your input id="email"

  $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
    });
   $.ajax({
    //url:"{{ route('emailvalicontroller.check') }}",
    url: emailCheckUrl,
    method:"POST",
    data:{email:email},
    error:function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      alert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);
    },
    success:function(data)
    {
     if(result == 'unique')
     {
      $('#error_email').html('<label class="text-success">Email Available</label>');
      $('#email').removeClass('has-error');
      $('#register').attr('disabled', false);
     }
     else
     {
      $('#error_email').html('<label class="text-danger">Email not Available</label>');
      $('#email').addClass('has-error');
      $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     }
    }
   })
  }
 });
});
```

My routes in web.php are as follows:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/emailvali', 'EmailValiController@index');
Route::post('/emailvali/check', 'EmailValiController@check')->name('emailvalicontroller.check');
});
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class EmailValiController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
     return view('emailvali');
    }

    function check(Request $request)
    {
      if($request->get('email'))
      {
        $email = $request->get('email');
        $data = DB::table("users") //don't set prefix.
         ->where('email', $email)
         ->count();
        if($data > 0){ echo 'not_unique'; }
        else{ echo 'unique'; }
     }
    }
}
```

`myscript.js` is called correctly by `emailvali.blade.php` using `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/emailvali.js') }}"></script>`. `err.message` is empty, but the responseText contains `exception: Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException`. I think the problem isn't the token, otherwise there would be a token error message. What is not found here and how to fix it? Is it the `emailvalicontroller` which now can't be accessed from the js? Thanks.

The full xhr.responseText is:

```
Error: {
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\AbstractRouteCollection.php",
    "line": 43,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
            "line": 162,
            "function": "handleMatchedRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\AbstractRouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 639,
            "function": "match",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 628,
            "function": "findRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 617,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 165,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 128,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 63,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php",
            "line": 36,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 140,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 109,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\van\\public\\index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have a route named `emailvalicontroller.check`?

Comment: Yes, I just added my routing info to the question.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, please select it :)

Comment: A `NotFoundHttpException` in Laravel generally means it was not able to find a router for a particular URL. Check to see that the route url is passing correctly

Comment: I am relatively new to Laravel, could you give me a hint how to "Check to see that the route url is passing correctly"? When the js code was in the view all routing was fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JS file is not parsed by PHP. One of the nice ways to solve this problem is to inject the value first, then call the script, like this:

```php
// in your Blade template
<script>
const emailCheckUrl = @json(route('emailvalicontroller.check'));
</script>
<script src="/js/myscript.js"></script>
```

And then in your `/js/myscript.js`:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: emailCheckUrl,
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I get the idea but this gives me the same error / behaviour (also <script src="/js/myscript.js"></script> does not work here). Do you need any more info from my code?

Comment: You can put that script with `const emailCheckUrl = ...` just above your `<script src="...">`, no matter where it is, as long as it's a blade template.

Comment: Sure, the script is called correctly by using `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/myscript.js') }}"></script>` but still i get the error NotFoundHttpException.

Comment: Do you know what's not found? Check in dev tools Network tab what is being requested.

Comment: I'm on Firefox, using it's devtools but can't figure out what's missing but I'll give you the full responseText, maybe there's a clue. Added it to the question.

Comment: You need to check what URL is your script requesting. I can't do your job, I already gave you solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes, I set up a new database (identical to the first one) and restarted Wamp, then it worked for unknown reason, can't reproduce it. But I can tell for sure the injection you suggested above was part of the problem, so I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your `emailvali.blade.php` you should have this somewhere near the bottom:

```
<script> const emailRoute = @json(route('emailvalicontroller.check')); </script>
<script src="{{asset('js/emailvali.js')}}"></script>
```

And also a button to call the ajax request:

```
<button onclick="addSomething()">Add something</button>
```

Now, inside your `emailvali.js` file you should have something like this:

```
function addSomething(){

  let email = document.getElementById("email").value; //assuming your input id="email"

$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
    });
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: emailRoute,
        data: {email:email},
        success:function(data) {
            console.log("success");
            //add your success handling here
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("failed");
          //add your failed handling here
        },
    });
}
```

It's more ideal to include the CSRF token as a header in your Ajax setup, then make sure you have

```
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

in your `<head>` HTML.

Comment: That's pretty much what I did and I am still getting the same `NotFoundHttpException` from responseText. The script is definitely called and the first part (email format checking) correctly executed. It's definitely the Ajax part where the problem is. Could you give me a hint how to track this down, recommend any tools or practices for that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you know how to utilise Developer Tools in your browser? I can show you how to debug Ajax issues.

Comment: I am using Firefox (standard edition) and would highly appreciate if you could give me some debugging practice info. Or just hint me to a tutorial somewhere.

Comment: Before doing so, I feel as if there is a small mistype or mistake in your program. Are you able to edit your post with the full `myscript.js` code, as well as your HTML `form` you are posting with your AJAX request, and if you possible, post your full `web.php` routes file. The reason I say this is because `NotFoundHttpException ` means Laravel was not able to find a route for the request. So anywhere in your program with `emailvali` related logic that uses Routes... needs to be double checked. I'm able to reproduce this problem with the code I provided and it works fine for me.

Comment: Just did, the controller file as well. The html is accurate since the js is called properly (email format checking from emailvali.js works).